Error while installing amass snap package [ubuntu 24.04], what could be the problem?
I was trying to install amass snap package through sudo snap install amass. after few minutes I got error in my ubuntu terminal.
david@david:~/Desktop$ sudo snap install amass
[sudo] password for david: 
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "core20" (2318) from channel "stable" (download too slow: 0.00 bytes/sec)


since amass has not been updated since 16 April 2022 (see this Snapcraft post](https://snapcraft.io/install/amass/ubuntu) it's unlikely it has been updated to work with later versions of Ubuntu and more recent kernels

https://github.com/owasp-amass/amass how can I install it through open source ?

read further down the code page which you linked to,  to the Documentation section for installation instructions. Not sure that will work for the same reasons given anyway.

The fact that snap apparently can't download / install the core20 snap suggests a networking problem, no? What does snap info core20 say?

This Question can closed. as my problem has been resolved.
